# 'class' or 'interface' expected error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting a `class` or `interface` expected error. Does anybody know how to go about it? I am new to java and trying to learn! Thanks in advance.

```
public class RallyDevice {
    private int _sno;
    private Time _currentTime;
    private double _dist;
    private double _avgSpeed;
    private double _requiredTime;
    private Time _idealTime;
      }

    public RallyDevice(){}

    public RallyDevice(int sno, Time currentTime, double dist,double avgspeed,double requiredtime,Time idealtime) {
        this._sno = sno;
        this._currentTime = currentTime;
        this._dist = dist;
        this._avgSpeed = avgspeed;
        this._requiredTime = requiredtime;
        this._idealTime = idealtime;
    }

    public RallyDevice( Time currentTime, double dist,double avgspeed,double requiredtime,Time idealtime) {
        this._currentTime = currentTime;
        this._dist = dist;
        this._avgSpeed = avgspeed;
        this._requiredTime = requiredtime;
        this._idealTime = idealtime;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't ask the question...

Comment: You should learn some java basics or have to use better code formating ... this is compile time error prolly because too much `}`

Comment: I am sorry but I am weak in Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enclose your class inside with its overloaded constructor and not outside

```
public class RallyDevice 
{
    private int _sno;
    private Time _currentTime;
    private double _dist;
    private double _avgSpeed;
    private double _requiredTime;
    private Time _idealTime;
    public RallyDevice()
    {
    }

    public RallyDevice(int sno, Time currentTime, double dist,double avgspeed,double requiredtime,Time idealtime) 
    {
        this._sno = sno;
        this._currentTime = currentTime;
        this._dist = dist;
        this._avgSpeed = avgspeed;
        this._requiredTime = requiredtime;
        this._idealTime = idealtime;
    }

    public RallyDevice( Time currentTime, double dist,double avgspeed,double requiredtime,Time idealtime) 
    {
        this._currentTime = currentTime;
        this._dist = dist;
        this._avgSpeed = avgspeed;
        this._requiredTime = requiredtime;
        this._idealTime = idealtime;
    }
}
```